# Lua - table won't insert from function

Tags: lua, scope, insert, lua-table, love2d

I have a Lua function where I build a table of value and attempt to add it to a global table with a named key.

The key name is pulled from the function arguments. Basically, it's a filename, and I'm pairing it up with data about the file.

Unfortunately, the global table always comes back nil. Here's my code: (let me know if you need to see more)

(Commented parts are other attempts, although many attempts have been deleted already)

```
Animator = Class{}

    function Animator:init(atlasfile, stringatlasfriendlyname, totalanimationstates, numberofframesperstate, booleanstatictilesize)

        -- Define the Animator's operation mode. Either static tile size or variable.
        if booleanstatictilesize ~= false then
          self.isTileSizeStatic = true
        else
          self.isTileSizeStatic = false
        end

        -- Define the total animation states (walking left, walking right, up down, etc.)
        -- And then the total frames per state.
        self.numAnimationStates = totalanimationstates or 1
        self.numAnimationFrames = numberofframesperstate or 2

        -- Assign the actual atlas file and give it a programmer-friendly name.
        self.atlasname = stringatlasfriendlyname or removeFileExtension(atlasfile, 'animation')

        generateAnimationQuads(atlasfile, self.atlasname, self.numAnimationStates, self.numAnimationFrames)

    end

    function generateAnimationQuads(atlasfile, atlasfriendlyname, states, frames)

        spriteWidthDivider = atlasfile:getWidth() / frames
        spriteHeightDivider = atlasfile:getHeight() / states

        animationQuadArray = generateQuads(atlasfile, spriteWidthDivider, spriteHeightDivider)

        animationSetValues = {atlasarray = animationQuadArray, width = spriteWidthDivider, height = spriteHeightDivider}

        --gAnimationSets[#gAnimationSets+1] = atlasfriendlyname
        gAnimationSets[atlasfriendlyname] = animationSetValues
        --table.insert(gAnimationSets, atlasfriendlyname)

    end
```

Note: when using print(atlasfriendlyname) and print(animationSetValues), neither are empty or nil. They both contain values.

For some reason, the line(s) that assign the key pair to gAnimationSets does not work.

gAnimationSets is defined a single time at the top of the program in main.lua, using

```
gAnimationSets = {}
```

Animator class is called during the init() function of a character class called Bug. And the Bug class is initialized in the init() function of StartState, which extends from BaseState, which simply defines dummy init(), enter(), update() etc. functions.

StartState is invoked in main.lua using the StateMachine class, where it is passed into StateMachine as a value of a global table declared in main.lua.

gAnimationSets is declared after the table of states and before invoking the state.

This is using the Love2D engine.

Sorry that I came here for help, I've been picking away at this for hours.

Edit: more testing.

Trying to print the animationQuadArray at the index gTextures['buganimation'] always returns nil. Huh?

Here's gTextures in Main.lua

```
gTextures = {
    ['background'] = love.graphics.newImage('graphics/background.png'),
    ['main'] = love.graphics.newImage('graphics/breakout.png'),
    ['arrows'] = love.graphics.newImage('graphics/arrows.png'),
    ['hearts'] = love.graphics.newImage('graphics/hearts.png'),
    ['particle'] = love.graphics.newImage('graphics/particle.png'),
    ['buganimation'] = love.graphics.newImage('graphics/buganimation.png')
}
```

Attempting to return gTextures['buganimation'] returns a file value as normal. It's not empty.

My brain is so fried right now I can't even remember why I came to edit this. I can't remember.

Global table in Main.lua, all other functions can't access it.

print(gTextures['buganimation']) works inside the function in question. So gTextures is absolutely accessible.

Table isn't empty. AnimationSetValues is not empty.

Comment: I tested some more and it seems that Lua can't edit a global table from inside a function? Huh?

I created a random empty table and assigned a value to it from within a random function. Nil every time.

And, obviously, return doesn't work either. Tried that plenty. Doesn't even make sense to use it in this case, but I tried anyway.

Comment: Post the simplified example of the problem - may make it easier to find a solution

Comment: All temporary variables should be local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm adding second answer because both are correct in context.

I ended up switching IDE's to VS Code and now the original one works.

I was originally using Eclipse LDT with a Love2D interpreter and in that environment, my original answer is correct, but in VS Code, the original is also correct.

So Dimitry was right, they are equivalent, but something about my actual Eclipse setup was not allowing that syntax to work.

I switched to VS Code after I had another strange syntax problem with the interpreter where goto syntax was not recognized and gave a persistent error. The interpreter thought goto was the name of a variable.

So I switched, and now both things are fixed. I guess I just won't use LDT for now.

Answer (score -2):

Solution: Lua syntax. Brain Fry Syndrome

I wrote:

```
animationSetValues = {atlasarray = animationQuadArray, width = spriteWidthDivider, height = spriteHeightDivider}
```

Should be:

```
animationSetValues = {['atlasfile']=atlasfile, ['atlasarray']=animationQuadArray, ['width']=spriteWidthDivider, ['height']=spriteHeightDivider}
```

---

Edit: I'm fully aware of how to use answers. This was posted here to reserve my spot for an answer so I could edit it later when I returned back home, which is exactly what I'm doing right now. I'll keep the old post for archival purposes.

---

Original:
I solved it. I apologize for not posting the solution right now. My brain is melted into gravy.

I will post it tomorrow. Just wanted to "answer" saying no need to help. Solved it.

Solution is basically, "oh it's just one of those Lua things". Wonderful. I'm having so much fun with this language - you can tell by my blank expression.

From the language without line endings or brackets, but forced print parentheses... ugh. I'm going back to C# when this class is done.

Comment: You're not telling the whole story. It's incorrect to say that Lua "can't edit a global table", unless there's specially created conditions preventing that - like sandboxing. See the example that modifies global table from within function: https://ideone.com/HFB2IY

Comment: The lines presented in  "I wrote" and "Should be" are equivalent in lua.

Comment: That could be true, and I don't doubt that it is, but somehow, some way, "should be" works, and "I wrote" doesn't. That's why I tagged this as Love2D. I suspected it might have been a Love2D related issue and not Lua, because the research I did before posting this did indeed tell me that the two were equivalent. Yet, it didn't work. I'm sure you're correct, but the results speak for themselves. That means there's another factor at play: Love2D, I suspect. I don't know anything about Lua, so I can't really figure it out.

Comment: Ran out of characters, posting a second comment. Maybe it's not Love2D at all - maybe it's the Class file? I used Class.lua recommended by the GD50 professor.